# Using timestampdiff in a Derby WHERE clause

Tags: sql, derby, javadb

I would like to simulate the effect of the following type of query (that is in Microsoft SQL Server syntax) in a Derby database.  The goal is to return all records in the table where the date stored in "someColumn" is less than 7 days old.  Here is the Microsoft SQL syntax for what I wish to achieve...

`select * from someTable where datediff(dd, someColumn, getdate()) < 7`

I have been able to determine that in Derby it will involve use of the timestampdiff function.  But the syntax of the usage of functions in a WHERE clause in Derby is unknown to me and I cannot find any examples.  I have found many examples where a function is used in the "what to return" clause, such as this...

`select {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_HOUR, startdate, enddate)} as diff`

But I have not found an example of how to use such a function in a WHERE clause.

I acknowledge that my question is really "how do I use a function in a Derby WHERE clause", and yes, it's pretty basic.  I also swear that I have really tried hard to find examples before posting.  I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see an example in the original patch [email](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/db-derby-dev/200505.mbox/%3C4284D2C1.3090902@sbcglobal.net%3E),

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE {fn TIMESTAMPDIFF( SQL_TSI_DAY, CURRENT_DAY, promisedDate)} <= 1
```

Comment: Replace CURRENT_DAY for CURRENT_DATE